# deploying flask application using gunicorn throws OSError: [Errno 0] Error

Tags: python-3.x, flask, gunicorn

deploying flask application using gunicorn  throws `OSError: [Errno 0] Error` everytime.

The beow is the error:

```
[2021-06-28 12:00:21 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Socket error processing request.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 135, in handle
req = next(parser)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/http/parser.py", line 42, in __next__
self.mesg = self.mesg_class(self.cfg, self.unreader, self.source_addr, self.req_count)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/http/message.py", line 180, in __init__
super().__init__(cfg, unreader, peer_addr)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/http/message.py", line 54, in __init__
unused = self.parse(self.unreader)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/http/message.py", line 192, in parse
self.get_data(unreader, buf, stop=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/http/message.py", line 183, in get_data
data = unreader.read()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/http/unreader.py", line 37, in read
d = self.chunk()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gunicorn/http/unreader.py", line 64, in chunk
return self.sock.recv(self.mxchunk)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1226, in recv
return self.read(buflen)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1101, in read
return self._sslobj.read(len)
OSError: [Errno 0] Error
```

Environment details:

Python version: Python 3.8.5

guncorn module version: 20.0.4

gunicorn config file:

```
"""Gunicorn configurations."""
import os

bind = "0.0.0.0:443"
workers = os.cpu_count() - 1
keyfile = "/home/xyz/certs/psa_xyz.key"
certfile = "/home/xyz/certs/psa_xyz.crt"
timeout = 120
```

Answer (score 0):

Either another application is already using that port or you have a firewall issue blocking you from accessing that port. To confirm that, you can try changing the port to 5000.

So your config should look something like this.

```
"""Gunicorn configurations."""
import os

bind = "0.0.0.0:5000"
workers = os.cpu_count() - 1
keyfile = "/home/xyz/certs/psa_xyz.key"
certfile = "/home/xyz/certs/psa_xyz.crt"
timeout = 120
```